# Getting statuscode = 400 while using http.get from dart/flutter on local ip address

Tags: json, http, flutter, dart, dart-http

## My goal:

I want to make a get request to the RestApi that is running on the device in my local network to retrieve JSON data generated by the device.

### What happens

The RestApi correctly responds to the browser call from every other device in the network. Bash's curl also works, **however when I try to access the data through dart's http.get the program fails to retrieve the JSON data - I'm getting Statuscode 400.**

### Browser call result

### What I have tried:

- Messing with URL to make sure it's written correctly,
- Setting up headers {"content" : "application/json"}
- Using no (default) headers
- Running the API call from separate dart file and from function embedded in flutter app. Both resulted in Statuscode 400, though flutter provided some more bug information: 
  Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: No route to host, errno = 113. I believe I have also seen the errno = 111 when I tried something else.
- Using lower level HttpClient instead of Http

In the flutter app, I can connect to the data stored on firebase through http.get easily enough, but call to the device in local network results in the scenario described above.

### Stand-alone dart file

```
import 'package:dart_http/dart_http.dart' as dart_http;
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';

main(List<String> arguments) async {

  var url = 'http://192.168.0.5/api/device/state';

  http.Response response1 =
      await http.get(url, headers: {"content": "application/json"});
  print('Response status: ${response1.statusCode}');
  print('Response body: ${response1.body}');
  print('Response body: ${response1.headers}');
  print('Response body: ${response1.reasonPhrase}');
  print('Response body: ${response1.request}');

  HttpClient()
      .getUrl(Uri.parse(
          'http://192.168.0.5/api/device/state/')) // produces a request object
      .then((request) => request.close()) // sends the request
      .then((response) {
    print(response);
    response.transform(Utf8Decoder()).listen(print);
  }); // transforms and prints the response
}
```

### Call-embedded in flutter project

```
 Future<Map<String, String>> getAirSensorStatus() async {
    print("Getting Air Sensor");
http.Response response =
        await http.get('http://192.168.0.5/api/device/state');
        print(response);
        print("Status code  " + "${response.statusCode}");

    try {
      if (response.statusCode != 200 && response.statusCode != 201) {
        print("Something went wrong. Status not 200 and not 201 for AirSensor");
        return null;
      }
      final responseData = json.decode(response.body);

      return responseData;
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
      return null;
    }
  }
```

I'm expecting to get statuscode 200 and JSON data in the response. Instead, only a response object is created and no connection established.

Could you help me figure out why is that?

### The link to the documentation of the API I'm trying to access:

https://technical.blebox.eu/

Comment: Did you maybe fall trap to `flutter_test` [overriding the HTTP client](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/35318) and then defaults to returning HTTP 400?

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems likely to be caused by the client unable to reach the local server on the request. [HTTP error 400](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) is labelled as "Bad request" and "No route to host, errno = 113" usually caused by network error. A [common fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60687062/2497859) to this issue is to ensure that the client is on the same network the local server is hosted in.