# Flutter SocketException: OS Error: No route to host, errno = 113, address = xxxx, port = 42376

Tags: android, api, flutter, postman

I received this error

```
Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: No route to host,
errno = 113, address = (my url api), port = 42392
```

while trying to access it with this code:

```
final String basicAuth = 'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode('$authUsername:$authPassword'));
final String _grantType = "password";

http.Response response = await http.post(
  Uri.encodeFull("this is my url api"),
  headers: <String, String>{
    "authorization": basicAuth,
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  },
  body: {
    "username": username,
    "password": password,
    "grant_type": _grantType,
  },
);
```

I've tried the URL using postman and work perfectly, did I write it correctly?  I'm not sure about placing authorization basic auth code

Comment: Is the device connected to Internet ? Or has network access to the API ?

Comment: It was connected, but its already worked now. And turns out it was because the API is placed in private server and i have to change my phone network to local wifi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLVED !!!!**

if you want access api from external device so you need to be at same network with local host to do that click on this link to help you connect to local host.

[How can I access my localhost from my Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device)

- If you run Xammp as virtual machine it will host your files with different ip like **(192.168.64.2)** so to make it host on local host you need activate port forwarding rules 
  from :
  open

**Xammp -> Network -> enable ;**

hope this help you .

Comment: problem is solved already, turns out it was because i got to connect on wrong wifi and the api that i want to connect is in local network

Comment: my network is also same still facing the same issue

Comment: Stuck with this issue since morning i am using nodejs with mongoodb for my flutter project

Answer (score 1):

**Firt Solution**
Check that your device and your server are connected to the same network

**Second Solution**
Just reboot your router